# Quadratic and cubic spline

Tags: spline

Can somebody help me with this?
I have to find the quadratic spline $s_Q$, when I know:
$$
i  = 1 \quad 2 \quad 3 \quad 4
$$
$$
x_i = −1 \quad  1 \quad  2 \quad  3
$$
$$
y_i = −2  \quad 0  \quad −1  \quad 0
$$
 and $s_Q'(x_4) = 1$.

And I have to find cubic spline $s_C$, when I know:
$s_C''(x_1) = 0$, and $s_C'(x_4) = −1$.

Comment: what are "s'quad(x4)=1" and "s''cub(x1)"?

Comment: I tidied up the question. Please make sure I didn't change your intended meaning.